# Сохранение и вывод изображения в представлении

Tags: c#, файлы, asp.net-mvc, mvc

В get-методе пользователь загружает два файла- изображение и текстовый файл. В Post-методе идет обработка этих файлов, в результате генерируется новое изображение. Мне нужно вывести это изображение в представлении. Но когда я вывожу это изображение, мне показывает иконку изображения, а не само изображение. Насколько я понимаю, я неправильно сохраняю это сгенерированное изображение. Подскажите, как правильно вывести это изображение в представление? 
Код контроллера:

```
 private string GetUniqueFileName(string fileName)
    {
        fileName = Path.GetFileName(fileName);
        return Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName)
                + "_"
                + Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Substring(0, 4)
                + Path.GetExtension(fileName);
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Encrypted(HttpPostedFileBase upload1, HttpPostedFileBase upload2, string key)
    {
        var baseLocation = Server.MapPath("~/Files/");

        var fileName1 = GetUniqueFileName(upload1.FileName);
        var fileLocation1 = Path.Combine(baseLocation, fileName1);
        upload1.SaveAs(fileLocation1);

        var fileName2 = GetUniqueFileName(upload2.FileName);
        var fileLocation2 = Path.Combine(baseLocation, fileName2);
        upload2.SaveAs(fileLocation2);


            Image image = Image.FromStream(upload2.InputStream);
            image.Save(fileLocation2);
            string imagePath = fileLocation2;
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(imagePath);

            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileLocation1);
            string text = sr.ReadLine();
            text = Crypto.EncryptStringAES(text, key);

            Bitmap bmp1 = SteganoHelper.embedText(text, bmp);

            byte[] arr = bmp1.ToByteArray(ImageFormat.Png);
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(arr);
        Image imageResult = Image.FromStream(ms);


        var fileNameRes = Path.GetRandomFileName();
        var fileLocationRes = Path.Combine(baseLocation, fileNameRes);

        imageResult.Save(fileLocationRes);

        TempData["ImageLocation"] = fileNameRes;
        return RedirectToAction("Preview");

        //return File(arr, "image/png");

    }

    public ActionResult Preview()
    {
        var vm = new PreviewImageVm();
        var fileName = TempData["ImageLocation"] as string;
        vm.ImageName = fileName;
        return View(vm);
    }
```

Как я вывожу изображение в представлении:

```
<img src="@Url.Content("~/Files/"+ Model.ImageName)" alt="my image" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var fileNameRes = Path.ChangeExtension(Path.GetRandomFileName(), ".png");
```